# Event handler without anonymous function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a jQuery plugin and the following script works perfect.  Is there a better way to do it without using the anonymous function.  Thanks

```
$('.sortName').selectIt({
    'title':'Title',
    'click':function(value){someFunction(value);}
});

function someFunction(value){alert(value);}
```

Comment: It totally depends on your plugin. In the general case, no, there is no better solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pass the function itself instead of passing an anonymous function.

```
$('.sortName').selectIt({
    'title':'Title',
    'click':someFunction
});
```

Comment: It doesn't allow to pass a value, which is obviously what is asked.

Comment: What about passing function arguments?!

Comment: @dystroy: The value being passed to `someFunction` is the argument passed to the anonymous function.

Comment: @roasted: The argument is still being passed. There's no need for an intermediary function.

Comment: @user1689607 Say you have a value, when calling selectIt : how do you pass it to someFunction. You don't.

Comment: Yes, I tried this before posting the question, but couldn't pass value.  I thought that JavaScript might allow it  to be passed without explicitly stating it, but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: @user1032531: Yes, this will work. The `value` argument will be passed to `someFunction` just like it's being passed to the anonymous function.

Comment: @dystroy this answer is correct with the example given. I am not sure what you are talking about.

Comment: Do I leave function someFunction(value){alert(value);} the same way?  I've tested and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @user1032531: Yes, that should be the same. Just make sure you don't include the `()` after the `someFunction`

Comment: I had been making a dummy mistake.  Works perfect.  Thanks!

Comment: Read dystroy answer: "if the callback isn't immediately called" should give strange result. Its depend from how is set your value.

Comment: @roasted: It will make no difference. The callback can make no use of the outer `value` variable because it has its own `value` parameter.

Comment: @roasted Wrong, you and dystroy just reinvented variable scoping!

Comment: I think this answer is correct, because the plug-in will not (and cannot) distinguish if it's calling anonymous function or pre-defined function accepting the same parameters. I see no alternative here, unless the anonymous function is going to add some extra work/context modifications before calling pre-defined function.